# SSRS 2017 use windows authentication

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

How can I bypass entering a user name/password in SSRS?? We have a TV that displays a report. I need the report to open & display without having to enter the user name/password.

I have attempted making changes in the rsreportserver.config based on this article, but could not get it to work...

[Configure Windows Authentication on the Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/configure-windows-authentication-on-the-report-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: If the report has a set username and password then it should not ask for credentials! what are your site and report settings? Too many unanswered questions here

Comment: AD groups are use for report access. Groups are given access to to report folders, report security is inherited from the folder.

Comment: so for the report that you want displayed on the TV, are you not able to use a SQL login or the likes and have it set in the datasource to use that instead of the AD login?